# Sorting Listview in Android Studio By Time(HH:mm)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

> I have the "questTime" column in the sqlite database that contains hour and minute.I want to sort the ListView objects in my Android app by this hour and minute.

### Database

```
db.execSQL("create table questions(_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
            "stuId integer," +
            "lesson text not null," +
            "subject text not null," +
            "questPhoto blob," +
            "answer text not null," +
            "questTime text," +
            "point integer not null)");
```

### Item Class

```
public class ItemQuestions {

String strkonu,strpuan,strgonderen,strtime;
Bitmap imgsoru,imguserinquest;


public ItemQuestions(){

}


public ItemQuestions(String strkonu, String strpuan, String strgonderen, String strtime,
                     Bitmap imgsoru, Bitmap imguserinquest){
    this.strkonu=strkonu;
    this.strpuan=strpuan;
    this.strgonderen=strgonderen;
    this.strtime=strtime;
    this.imgsoru=imgsoru;
    this.imguserinquest=imguserinquest;
}

public String getStrtime() {
    return strtime;
}

public void setStrtime(String strtime) {
    this.strtime = strtime;
}

public String getStrkonu() {
    return strkonu;
}

public void setStrkonu(String strkonu) {
    this.strkonu = strkonu;
}

public String getStrpuan() {
    return strpuan;
}

public void setStrpuan(String strpuan) {
    this.strpuan = strpuan;
}

public String getStrgonderen() {
    return strgonderen;
}

public void setStrgonderen(String strgonderen) {
    this.strgonderen = strgonderen;
}

public Bitmap getImgsoru() {
    return imgsoru;
}

public void setImgsoru(Bitmap imgsoru) {
    this.imgsoru = imgsoru;
}

public Bitmap getImguserinquest() {
    return imguserinquest;
}

public void setImguserinquest(Bitmap imguserinquest) {
    this.imguserinquest = imguserinquest;
}
```

}

### Adapter Class

```
public class AdapterQuestions extends ArrayAdapter<ItemQuestions> {

Context context;
ArrayList<ItemQuestions> listarrayforQuest=new ArrayList<ItemQuestions>();
private int resource;

public AdapterQuestions(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ItemQuestions> listarrayforQuest) {
    super(context, resource, listarrayforQuest);
    this.context=context;
    this.resource=resource;
    this.listarrayforQuest=listarrayforQuest;
}

class ViewYerTutucu{
    TextView tvholder_strkonu, tvholder_strpuan, tvholder_strgonderen, tvholder_strtime;
    ImageView imgholder_seen, imgholder_imgsoru, imgholder_comment;
    CircleImageView crcimgholder_imguserinquestions;

    ViewYerTutucu(View v){
        imgholder_imgsoru= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgviewinquestions);
        imgholder_seen= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgviewseeninquest);
        imgholder_comment= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgviewcommentinquest);
        tvholder_strkonu= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtkonuinquest);
        tvholder_strpuan= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtpuaninquest);
        tvholder_strgonderen= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtgondereninquest);
        tvholder_strtime= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtquestiondate);
        crcimgholder_imguserinquestions= (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.crcimguserfotoinquest);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View viewquest=convertView;
    ViewYerTutucu tutucu=null;

    if(viewquest==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewquest=inflater.inflate(resource,null);
        tutucu=new ViewYerTutucu(viewquest);
        viewquest.setTag(tutucu);
    }
    else {
        tutucu= (ViewYerTutucu) viewquest.getTag();
    }

    ItemQuestions itemQuestions=listarrayforQuest.get(position);

    tutucu.tvholder_strkonu.setText(itemQuestions.getStrkonu());
    tutucu.tvholder_strpuan.setText(itemQuestions.getStrpuan());
    tutucu.tvholder_strgonderen.setText(itemQuestions.getStrgonderen());
    tutucu.tvholder_strtime.setText(itemQuestions.getStrtime());

    tutucu.imgholder_imgsoru.setImageBitmap(itemQuestions.getImgsoru());
    tutucu.crcimgholder_imguserinquestions.setImageBitmap(itemQuestions.getImguserinquest());

    return viewquest;



}
```

}

> View in ListView
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di1Kr.jpg)
>
> I searched many examples of ListView sorting, buy I want to sort according to time(HH:mm).So, how can I ensure that the object with the most current time is at the top of the ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you using the combination of RecyclerView, an Adapter and [SortedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html) which keeps elements in order. You can also get notification about changes in that list through a [Callback object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.Callback.html).

I'd loved to write an article about this, but [someone already did a good job](https://medium.com/@jszczygiel/sortedlist-write-your-recycleview-without-an-index-c00ca92c0ca6) explaining it well.

If you still want to use a ListView, I think you will have to manually sort objects after any change (and before calling notifyDatasetChanged). I mean by sorting, `select * order by xxx` again or sorting your collection with Java, whatever you need.